# Is there a way to fetch past (or at least the last) "print" calls?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
print "Hello"
print "Goodbye"
```

Is there any way to fetch what was said in those print calls?

Example:

```
print "The last print was", output.previousMessage()
```

Comment: I don't think you can because neither the `print` statement (Python 2) nor the `print` function (Python 3) have a return value - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I haven seen anything like that, but you may always make your own print class that can save the last message so you can retrieve it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> last_print = None
>>>
>>> # this class will replace sys.stdout
>>> class PrintCatcher:
...     # catch and save writes (prints)
...     def write(self, data):
...         global last_print
...         if data != "\n": last_print = data
... 
...         # write the data to the original stdout object
...         sys.__stdout__.write(data)
...         sys.__stdout__.flush()
...
...     # forward attribute gets to the original stdout object
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         return getattr(sys.__stdout__, attr)
... 
>>> print "Hello"
Hello
>>> last_print
>>> sys.stdout = PrintCatcher()
>>> print "Goodbye"
Goodbye
>>> last_print
'Goodbye'
```

Essentially, you are replacing `sys.stdout` (which is the file-like object `print` writes to) with your own wrapper object that records the data and forwards the data to `sys.__stdout` (which is always the original `sys.stdout`).

This is not perfect though, as you can see it will ignore newlines, so if you do `print` without any arguments it won't record it.

If you want to record all prints, simply make `last_print` a list and append all messages to it instead of assigning only the last print to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `print` by default outputs to stdout, maybe you could redirect it and intercept what passes through... For example:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

newout = StringIO()

# Redirect
sys.stdout = newout
print "Hello" # Nothing gets printed

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print "Back to normal"
print newout.getvalue() # Prints "Hello"
```

Of course you'd have to implement a subclass of StringIO, if you want `print` to display something even while in "capture" mode.

Comment: The original `stdout` is always available in `sys.__stdout__`, so there's no need for the `oldout` variable.